# tf.train.range_input_producer doesnot work

Tags: tensorflow

there ,I am new to tensorflow,when I am trying tf.train.range_input_producer, it does not work from my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            queue = tf.train.range_input_producer(tf.Variable(5, tf.int8), num_epochs=1, shuffle=True, seed=None,
                                                  capacity=32)
            # Start input enqueue threads.
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
            # Run training steps or whatever
            print('queue size:{}'.format(sess.run(queue.size())))
            coord.request_stop()
            # Terminate as usual.  It is innocuous to request stop twice.
            coord.join(threads)
            sess.close()
```

I get the size of my queue is :0

what is  the wrong going on with my code ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expected the size is 32,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize local and global variables before starting queue runners.

```py
sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()])
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!